# Serving different backends under the same Nginx server block w/o redirects

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a rails app serving a production site `https://example.com`. I also have a WordPress blog for that same site at `https://blog.example.com`. For maintenance and marketing reasons we'd like to have constantly changing urls in the main site like `/about`, `/faq`, etc to be managed with WordPress but served under the main site, such that -

`https://example.com/about` will render `https://blog.example.com/about` but not redirect there, same with `https://example.com/faq`, as if they were mounted under that main domain.

`https://example.com/anything-else` will use the the rails backend, etc.

Obviously this could be accomplished with a simple redirect, but **I'd like to keep the same URLs** - is that possible? I tried using `proxy_pass` but ended up getting redirects to the new urls:

```
server {
    # WordPress configuration
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name blog.example.com;
    root /var/www/blog;

    #...
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default;
    # .. misc SSL settings

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/example;

    # .. misc settings

    location /about {
        # ... render blog.example.com/about
    }

    location /faq {
        # ... render blog.example.com/faq
    }

    location @unicorn {
        # ... unicorn configuration
    }
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you will tell nginx to proxy certain requests to another server ( which in this case is the wordpress )

```
sever {
  #this is the rails server

  # These are all the locations combined into one condition
  # or you can split them to different locations if u want
  location /(faq|about|whatever) {
    # asking nginx to proxy these requests to this URL
    proxy_pass http://blog.example.com;
  }

  # The remaining cases that don't match the above criteria,
  # in your case this is where you want to pass to rails.
  location / {
    # remaining of rails settings
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You might get more upvotes that way!